# Manually call draw for matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code example. When I press the button the color changes. However only after I move the mouse a little. Can I somehow directly call the draw function?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

def toggle(_):
    button.status ^= True

    color = [0, 1, 0] if button.status else [1, 0, 0]
    button.color = color
    button.hovercolor = color

    # Stuff that doesn't work...
    plt.draw()
    button.canvas.draw()
    plt.gcf().canvas.draw()


button = Button(plt.axes([.1, .1, .8, .8]), 'Press me')
button.status = True
button.on_clicked(toggle)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure that there is an "official" way to do what you want to do, but here is a hack to simulate a mouse motion event which will trigger the redraw.  Add `button.canvas.motion_notify_event(0,0)` at the end of `toggle()` so that your code looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

def toggle(_):
    button.status ^= True

    color = [0, 1, 0] if button.status else [1, 0, 0]
    button.color = color
    button.hovercolor = color

    button.canvas.motion_notify_event(0,0)

button = Button(plt.axes([.1, .1, .8, .8]), 'Press me')
button.status = True
button.on_clicked(toggle)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and the answer by Eric Dill did not work for me. What worked instead was simply doing

```
canvas.draw_idle()
```

instead of

```
canvas.draw()
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64789437/what-is-the-difference-between-figure-show-figure-canvas-draw-and-figure-canva) for more information about the difference between the two.

I'm not sure if this works for all backends, but in my case I'm using GTK3Agg.

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks for the operator "^=". I didn't know that it works for bool type.

To solve your problem do not forget to set facecolor of the plt.axes:

```
ax = plt.axes([...])
button = Button(ax, ...)
ax.set(facecolor=color)
```

Now the button will change its color immediately after clicking. You do not have to move the mouse.

The full code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

ax = plt.axes([.1, .1, .8, .8])
button = Button(ax, 'Press me', color='#CCC', hovercolor='#CCC')


def toggle(event):
    button.status ^= True
    color = [0, 1, 0] if button.status else [1, 0, 0]
    button.color = color
    button.hovercolor = color
    ax.set(facecolor=color) # <<< THE TRICK !!!
    plt.draw()
    # button.canvas.draw() # also works
    # plt.gcf().canvas.draw() # also works


button.status = True
button.on_clicked(toggle)
plt.show()
```

I have Python 3.10.9 with matplotlib 3.7.1.

Good luck!