# Update a chart in realtime with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to update a plot by redrawing a new curve (with 100 points) in real-time.

This works:

```
import time, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, numpy as np
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
t0 = time.time()
for i in range(10000000):
    x = np.random.random(100)
    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(x, color='b')
    fig.show()
    plt.pause(0.01)
    print(i, i/(time.time()-t0))
```

but there is only ~10 FPS, which seems slow.

What is the standard way to do this in Matplotlib?

I have already read [How to update a plot in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098131/how-to-update-a-plot-in-matplotlib) and [How do I plot in real-time in a while loop using matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874767/how-do-i-plot-in-real-time-in-a-while-loop-using-matplotlib) but these cases are different because they *add a new point to an existing plot*. In my use case, I need to redraw everything and keep 100 points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know any technique to gain an order of magnitude. Nevertheless you can slightly increase the FPS with

1. update the line data instead of creating a new plot with [`set_ydata`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_ydata) (and/or [`set_xdata`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_xdata))
2. use `Figure.canvas.draw_idle()` instead of `Figure.canvas.draw()` (cf. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64789437/what-is-the-difference-between-figure-show-figure-canvas-draw-and-figure-canva)).

Thus I would recommand you to try the following:

```
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
t0 = time.time()

x = np.random.random(100)
l, *_ = ax.plot(x, color='b')
fig.show()
fig.canvas.flush_events()
ax.set_autoscale_on(False)
for i in range(10000000):
    x = np.random.random(100)
    l.set_ydata(x)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
    print(i, i/(time.time()-t0))
```

Note that, as mentioned by @Bhargav in the comments, changing matplotlib [backend](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/backends.html#backends) can also help (e.g. `matplotlib.use('QtAgg')`).

I hope this help.

Comment: I've tried your code .It Jumped all away from 20 to 50 FPS...Try backends along with your edits...I got arround 70 FPS after uisng [backends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930524/how-can-i-set-the-backend-in-matplotlib-in-python)